# Monitor Azure SQL Database via Azure log analytics

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have a sql database. I need to get logs from sql database in log analytics workspace.
I enabled Diagnostic Settings for SQL Database. How do I query log in log analytics workspace?

For example, here is my sql query:

select * from Employees where Country = 'US'

Can I query something similar in log analytics? This is what worked for me in log analytics:

> AzureDiagnostics
> | where Category == "SQLSecurityAuditEvents"
> | sort by TimeGenerated desc

but how do I query select * from Employees where Country = 'US'?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking whether you can use some kind of SQL statements to query the logs? Or are you asking how to create queries in Log Analytics? You cannot perform `select * from Employees where Country = 'US'?` in a log analytics query and expect results from the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. With [log queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-query-overview)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better solution for you: [Azure SQL Analytics (Preview)](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-au/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.AzureSQLAnalyticsOMS?tab=Overview)

Just go to the Azure Marketplace and download it:

[image]

Setup the Log Analytics workspace following [this guide][3].

[3]: https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-azure-sql-analytics/#:~:text=Azure%20SQL%20Analytics%20(Preview%20function,data%20collection%20across%20multiple%20subscriptions.